# how to add search filter in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on `UITableView` where I have a list of contacts. All the contacts are coming form a webservice in JSON format. I already parse it in my `tableView`, now I want to add a search logic to search contacts.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ChatListCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"contactListCell"];
 if(!cell){
     cell = [[ChatListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"contactListCell"];
 }
 ChatListData *chatlistData = [chatList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *txtName = chatlistData.name;
NSLog(@"name %@", txtName);
NSData *emojiData = [txtName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *emojiTxtName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:emojiData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
 cell.txtName.text = emojiTxtName;
 cell.txtTime.text = chatlistData.time;
 NSString *stringImg = @"image";
 NSString *stringVideo = @"video";
if(![chatlistData.mime_type isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
    if ([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringImg].location == NSNotFound || [chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringVideo].location == NSNotFound) {
            if ([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringImg].location == NSNotFound) {
                cell.txtMsg.text = @"Image";
            }else if([chatlistData.mime_type rangeOfString:stringVideo].location == NSNotFound){
                cell.txtMsg.text = @"Video";
            }
    }else {
        NSString *txtMsg = chatlistData.body;
        NSData *emojiData = [txtMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *emojiTxtMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:emojiData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        cell.txtMsg.text = emojiTxtMsg;
    }
}else {
    NSString *txtMsg = chatlistData.body;
    NSData *emojiData = [txtMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *emojiTxtMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:emojiData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    cell.txtMsg.text = emojiTxtMsg;

}
return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       //http://app.wazapper.com/api/users/inbox/45/#api_917838828123
       ChatListData *chatlistData = [chatList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       if(![chatlistData.contact isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
            NSString *chatUrl = [NSString            stringWithFormat:@"http://app.wazapper.com/api/users/inbox/%@/#api_%@", [[User  sharedInstance] userId], chatlistData.contact];
           chatViewController.chatUrl = chatUrl;
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]         postNotificationName:@"ChangeChatList" object:chatUrl];
      }
   }
```

this is my little piece of code, please give me some idea about it, I have already added the search bar in `UITableView`, I just need a logic for this purpose.

Comment: If u already have searchBar, u should make your VC confront the `UISearchBarDelegate` and add the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` and put your search logic (eg.forin or nspredicate) in there and update your tableview, `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` to cancel the search and return your normal data. And please edit your post to clearer format....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `UISearchBarDelegate` to your ViewController, then add this method to filter your search.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

NSPredicate *pre0 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Fname contains[cd] %@", searchText];

NSPredicate *pre1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Lname contains[cd] %@", searchText];

NSPredicate *preAll = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pre0, pre1]];

NSArray *filterAry=  [jsonAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:preAll];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

UI implementation:

```
- (void)setupSearchBar {
CGFloat ySearchBarPosition = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(viewBounds), ySearchBarPosition, CGRectGetWidth(viewBounds), kHeightDefault44)];
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.searchBar.barTintColor = kYourBarTintColor;
self.searchBar.tintColor = kYourTintColor;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"searchBar.placeholder", nil);
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *subSubview in subview.subviews) {
        if ([subSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subSubview;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            textField.backgroundColor = kColorUnregisteredDevicesSearchBarBackground;
            textField.textColor = kColorUnregisteredDevicesSearchBarText;
        }
        if ([subSubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            UIButton *cancelBarButton = (UIButton *)subSubview;
            cancelBarButton.tintColor = kColorUnregisteredDevicesSearchBarCancelButtonTintColor;
        }
    }
}
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

call this method where you create your tableView, before this line of code:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.yourTableView];
```

Functionality implementation:
1. You have to add **UISearchBarDelegate** on your .h class.
2. Use this delegation methods:

```
// delegation methods
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self reloadModelAndTable];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.searchBar.text = @"";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

// private methods
- (void)reloadModelAndTable:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self filterModelForSearch:self.searchBar.text];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)filterModelForSearch:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSMutableArray *records = (NSMutableArray *)[self.unregisteredDevicesList mutableCopy];

    NSIndexSet *resultSet = [records indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    YourModel *model = (YourModel *)obj;
    BOOL hasObjects = [self resultHasObjects:model withSearchText:searchText];
    return hasObjects;
}];

    self.yourArrayWhichPopulatesTheTable = [[records objectsAtIndexes:resultSet] mutableCopy];
}

- (BOOL)resultHasObjects:(YourModel *)model withSearchText:(NSString *)searchText{
    // I consider you make search for name
    return ((model.name.length > 0) && [self containsString:model.name searchText:searchText]);
}

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)haystack searchText:(NSString *)needle {
    if (haystack) {
        NSRange range = [haystack rangeOfString:needle options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
        return range.location != NSNotFound;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This code works perfect. Good luck! If something is not clear, please let me know.:)

Comment: this code is only for UI implementation. I will update the answer to add search bar functionality.

Comment: yes i add it perfectly now i need to know that, how will i compare my search string with the contact  in tableview which are come from json

Comment: It's very simple. in resultHasObjects: method , on YourModel parameter use ChatListData (I think this is the class which contains your objects from json), and inside of this method on return you will have : model.contact.length > 0 and model.contact as parameter of containsString method

Comment: Did you implemented this code? Is it working for you? @sandeeptomar

Comment: yeah its working fine in my app, but now i want to know how will i compare  search bar string with  json data. Thanks again

Comment: you make that compare in containsString:searchText: method. If this works for you, check the answer as response and magical thinks will happends =). @sandeeptomar

Comment: sorry ma'am its not work for me, can i show my code that how i read son and than how will  i wanted to add search filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97527/discussion-between-sandeep-tomar-and-adela).